# d3.js stacked bar chart: label beside every stack of the bar instead legend

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I'm using D3.js
Is there a way to reach a similar visualization with stack bar chart [image: stack bar chart]

where:

- the labels/annotations besides each stack (see above above link)
  where series labels beside each of the bars
- have rounded corners for each stack of the bar

thank you for your help

Comment: This example may be useful: http://bl.ocks.org/cbjuan/43f10523858abf6053ae
If you have problems to adapt the example to your design, post your code here and we will try to help

Comment: Hi Michael,
thank you... I will take a look on it and let you know if it help me.